# Is it possible to fully disable IRI in API Platform?

Tags: php, api-platform.com, iri

I wan't to make a "classic" API without IRI. I just want the ID in return, not an IRI nor the object/entity.

I already allow plain identifiers:

```
// config/packages/api_platform.yml
api_platform:
allow_plain_identifiers: true
```

If I make any request with Header Accept: application/json, it's still the same.

I I try to cheat and replace my getter of my linked entity by a getId()

```php
    public function getStatus(): AngelRelationshipStatus
    {
        return $this->status;
    }
```

by

```php
    public function getStatus(): int
    {
        return $this->status->getId();
    }
```

I'm getting the Following error : "Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given"

Why can't I just get a simple ID?

Environment:

- PHP 7.2
- API Platform 2.3

Comment: You could replace or decorate the IriConverter (<service id="ApiPlatform\Core\Api\IriConverterInterface" alias="api_platform.iri_converter" />) but that will change all iri's.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to not change too much under the hood with these hacky attempts to do unintended things (e.g. returning `id` for `status`).

Instead, simply customise your output during the Serialisation process.

See [Api-Platform Serialisation Process](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#the-serialization-process).

Comment: So let's take the bookshop example, how would one retrieve a list of review ids instead of a list of review IRIs?